# transfer files with ftp with ftpwebrequest

Tags: asp.net

currently I'm working on this ftp transfer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

I have setup my server computers iis to have a ftp site on port 21 and transfering files works great. But I want to add ftp to a hosted site I got on the server and it's here where I get the problems with connecting. when I try to connect through the command promt I get unknown host error. I have changed the port and open it up in firewall. and even if I could connect how can I decide what folder I want to upload to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You still have connecting problem with the server.. try ping command and see if you get unknown host error.
2. For the upload path issue, you need to give the full folder path to which you need to upload the file to. here is an example code:

   if (Site != null && FolderPath != null && FileName != null)
   {
      FTPrequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(CompletePath));
   }

Comment: completepath like this, fpt://mydomain.com/Upload/Images/file.txt?

Comment: yes.. complete path for the file ftp://mydomain.com/Upload/Images/file.txt .. the above code is what I am using.. Regarding ping.. check if you can access the ftp server using normal ping command

Comment: great that work with the path. still no luck with connecting to the other tho. I use a virtual name to that connection now. how should I add that to the ftp string in the uri with complete path..

Comment: can you explain your connection issue with more detail? You said you cannot connect in cmd.. ok, fine.. but when you try uploading, do you get any exception?

Comment: I can connect with the cmd now. sure I get this message.. Invalid URI: A port was expected because of there is a colon (':') present but the port could not be parsed.

I use this right now ftp://myip:21:ftp.file.com/Path/ its the same if i remove the port :21

Comment: well, that's a wrong url format. here is how it should be: ftp://my-ip-or-domain.com:port/folders/filename here is an example: ftp://dxphosting.com/asqcg/test.txt

Comment: but I got more then one ftp on this iis they all use the same ip and port so i got to use the virtual name. that how they recommend to do. any idea what more i could do?

Comment: If you are using the virtual host name, i don't think you need to give the domain and port again. it would be http://virtualname/path

Comment: Im not sure about that. cause that is only a internal. I dont put that in no other records like the AD of windows server. You and me could basicly have the same ftp.name.com and it would not know to who to connect if there is no Active Record. Ill see what they say over at the iis forum.. thanks for your time Abdel

if you figure something please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

While ping will tell you if the server exists, you should try to telnet directly to the port you are testing.

```
>> telnet url portnumber
>> telnet ftp.mydomain.com 21
```

If telnet is successful, you can be sure that the ftp port is active and accessible, then you can proceed to troubleshoot your problem.

Best practice is

> Do not try to automate a process which
>   you cannot complete manually.

Therefore, telnet, then test either ftp from command line or using a utility such as fireftp /cute ftp, whatever you choose.

If you are able to get a test like this to work, then you will be able to identify the exact cause of your trouble.

Once you have successfully tested access to your ftp site.
Pass in the complete URI to the FtpWebRequest.

Here is a function I created for testing.

```
public static void DoQueryAndUploadFile(string uri, string username, string password, string filename)
{
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri + "/" + filename);
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    ftp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ftp.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        // Do the query here then write to the ftp stream by iterating DataReader or other resultset, following code is just to demo concept:
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
                sw.WriteLine("{0},row-{1},data-{2}", i, i, i);
        }
        sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My connection work's but it's only it wont work when i try to connect through my code. My thing is I got 4 sites on my iis with ftp publishing, the ftp's use the same ip and same port, thats why I used virtual names. but maybe i was misstaken and virtual names need to actually be a registred domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem later that I had 2 ftp's on my iis with the same ip, so I used virtual names for them. I did not know how to connect to that from my code but this is just one of those stupid moments you go like ohh.
 solution was real easy so I thought I would share if any of you got the same issue as I did. key is to use the virtual name as a username and separate it with | and then actually write your real username.

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://IP:PORT/PATH/THE FILE"));
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("VIRTUAL NAME|MY USER", "MY PASSWORD");
```